# How to preserve extra column information when using sparse matrices?

Tags: python, scipy, networkx, sparse-matrix, tensor

I am trying find out how I can preserve extra information when using sparse matrices. I am writing some code that turns pandas dataframes into networks. The dataframe has a column with nodes, a column with edges, and some attribute columns.

```
>>> df.head()

  authors  papers     attr1             attr2
0       g  [4, 8]  yikpmrbf  FCCLYDWSFJVORGXL
1       h     [7]  zxdkzyam  DHJZADCAPRQYAXGR
2       c     [4]  lnynqqhf  PACVSZULQSKXBURW
3       k  [5, 3]  vjzgyebn  QMLHUIDWXGNPVQTH
4       r     [7]  etjghgcp  CSYIMFXKOYFWWUTH
```

So far, I have been using the following code to make a networkx graph, where `authors` are nodes which have edges if they share a value in `papers`.

```
from itertools import chain
import numpy as np
from scipy import sparse
import networkx as nx

node='authors'
link='papers'

indptr = np.fromiter(chain((0,), map(len, df[link])),
                     int, len(df[link])+1).cumsum()
unq, idx = np.unique(np.concatenate(df[link]), return_inverse=True)
node_link_matrix = sparse.csr_matrix(
    (np.ones(idx.size, int), idx, indptr),
    (len(df[link]),
     len(unq))
)
node_node_matrix = (node_link_matrix@node_link_matrix.T).tocoo()
G = nx.convert_matrix.from_scipy_sparse_matrix(node_node_matrix)
```

This calculates edge weights for each node-node pair in the data. `node_link_matrix` has as many rows as there are rows in the dataframe, and as many columns as there are unique edge-values (unique papers in this case). The values thus indicate "how many of x paper are present in x row". `node_node_matrix` is square and has as many rows/columns as there are rows in the dataframe. It is the dot product of `node_link_matrix` and `node_link_matrix` transposed. The values are edge weights, and this matrix can easily be turned into a graph with networkx.

```
>>> node_link_matrix
<74x10 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 140 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

>>> node_node_matrix
<74x74 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 1786 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
```

What I am trying is get information about the `attr1` column into this. I first tried replacing the "ones" with the actual attribute strings, so the previous code becomes:

```
from itertools import chain
import numpy as np
from scipy import sparse
import networkx as nx

node='authors'
link='papers'

indptr = np.fromiter(chain((0,), map(len, df[link])),
                     int, len(df[link])+1).cumsum()
unq, idx = np.unique(np.concatenate(df[link]), return_inverse=True)
node_link_matrix = sparse.csr_matrix(
    (np.repeat(df.attr1.values, np.diff(indptr)), idx, indptr),  # <-- Changed this part
    (len(df[link]),
     len(unq))
)
```

This doesn't work, as sparse matrices don't handle strings well. I tried to overcome this by replacing the actual values with a dictionary mapping each occurrence to the correct attribute

```
from itertools import chain
import numpy as np
from scipy import sparse
import networkx as nx

node='authors'
link='papers'

indptr = np.fromiter(chain((0,), map(len, df[link])),
                     int, len(df[link])+1).cumsum()
unq, idx = np.unique(np.concatenate(df[link]), return_inverse=True)
node_link_matrix = sparse.csr_matrix(
    (range(idx.size), idx, indptr),  # <-- Values are now IDs
    (len(df[link]),
     len(unq))
)

edge_attr_dict = dict(zip(range(idx.size), np.repeat(df.attr1.values, np.diff(indptr))))
```

This, then, gives me a `node_link_matrix` mapping nodes values to edge values and their corresponding attr1 value. The problem is, since the values now are symbolic numbers and not just ones and zeros, the dot product function to get the node-node relationship don't work anymore. So what I need is a way to retain the node attribute information in the sparse matrix, but still be able to use the dot product function as it is meant to. I have been considering whether this could be done by "pushing" the attribues into a third dimension, using a 3d tensor instead of a sparse matrix, but I don't have much experience with this.

Comment: Sparse is intended purely for numeric work; optimally coded for the dot product (since its origins are in linear algebra).  So the `data`, `indices` and `indptr` arrays contain all of the `csr` information.

Comment: Right, thanks. I was wondering though if by making a dictionary of the attributes with numeric keys this could be circumvented.

Comment: I'm sure the use of sparse matrices for various forms of big-data and machine learning, involves some forms of mapping or lookup, both for indices and data, but I haven't paid much attention to those.

Comment: Yeah I agree, thanks for the input 

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you can use arbitrary dtypes with a sparse matrix. `np.dtype('U10')` would be a 10-character unicode string. The easiest thing might be to build your edge table and then build a data array with `attr1` by hand.

Comment: Alternatively it seems your attributes are node attributes and not edge attributes; a package like [AnnData](https://anndata.readthedocs.io/en/latest/anndata.AnnData.html) would be best if you want to keep track of node metadata for an edge table.

Comment: Thanks @CJR. `np.dtype('U10')` might be useful. I agree that they seem like node attributes, but I am building a general script where users may choose to to use them as either node or edge attributes, which can be useful in some circumstances where attribute columns actually give information on edges and not nodes. My problem with just using the `np.dtype('U10')` is that I would still only be able to get the `node_link_matrix` in my previous example, not the `node_node_matrix, because the dot product won't work the same way as just multiplying 1's and 0's. Do you think AnnData will help?

Comment: Besides, I don't think csr matrices support `np.dtype('U10')` (https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/sparse/generate_sparsetools.py#L137)

Comment: I didn't know that sparse matrices wouldn't take most structured data, that's inconvenient. Frankly I think working with your current table is just making things needlessly difficult. I'd convert it to a standard node1-node2-edge_info table and go from there. You're not going to save that much in memory with a COO matrix over a pandas edge table to make it worth pulling your hair out.

Comment: Cool, thanks. I’ll try that. Sorry to keep bothering you, but could you point me in the direction of how I might convert the previous data into that kind of format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a reasonably quick way to reprocess your table to something which is `Node 1` -`Node 2` - `Edge attributes`.

```
edges = []

for p, group in df.explode("papers").groupby("papers"):

    # Add a new author2 edge column and explode it
    authors = group["authors"].tolist()
    group = group.copy() # This explicit copy suppresses an implicit-copy warning
    group["author2"] = [authors for _ in range(group.shape[0])]
    group = group.explode("author2")

    # Get rid of self-interaction rows
    edges.append(group.loc[group["authors"] != group["author2"], :])

edges = pd.concat(edges)
edges.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

This will be bigger memory-wise than a COO matrix, but as long as your data isn't extremely large the flexibility of having a dataframe is worth it.

Comment: Great, thanks! I'll still be working on the sparse method as well, as I do have very big datasets to work with, but this is great!

Comment: To be clear, this is a sparse method. What you're saving is the overhead from a data frame (which won't be that much if you factorize the node columns). Conceptually it is exactly the same as a coo-type sparse matrix and you can very easily build a coo Boolean matrix from it.